# Not able to use order by in Union query

Tags: mysql, union

I have the below original mysql query

```
select *, r.ReviewId AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r LEFT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId where r.DishId = ?
      UNION
      select *, r.ReviewId  AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r RIGHT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId where r.DishId = ?
```

I am trying to add order by so that i can sort the data by date but it is giving me below error

```
#1250 - Table 'rp' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in ORDER clause
```

Here is the modified query below:

```
(select *, r.ReviewId AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r LEFT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId where r.DishId = 46)
      UNION
      (select *, r.ReviewId  AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r RIGHT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId where r.DishId = 46) order by rp.DateCreated desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last query should work if you remove the alias from the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
(SELECT *, r.ReviewId AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated
 FROM review r
 LEFT JOIN reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId
 WHERE r.DishId = 46)
 UNION
(SELECT *, r.ReviewId, r.DateCreated
 FROM review r
 RIGHT JOIN reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId
 WHERE r.DishId = 46)
ORDER BY ActualDateCreated DESC;
```